# TYPO3: Publish workspace edit via scheduler?

Tags: typo3, scheduler, workspace, typo3-4.5

I managed to run the scheduler with a cron task.
I managed to auto publish a whole workspace on the publish date with the scheduler.

But I don't want the whole workspace to be published on the scheduler task, but only a single edit.

I tried to give the edit in the workspace a publish date, but that didn't work out.
Is this even possible?

TYPO3 version: 4.5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another Workspace for this single edit. And publish this different workspace where you have only one edit.

If you give some more details, perhaps it is possible to do it without workspaces? F.e. you can create two content elements with different start and stop dates.

Comment: I thought about a solution with no workspace, too, but I changed the layout setting for a bunch of pages. This cannot be solved with starttime fields.

Comment: About the new Workspace idea. This should work. Do you think, it is a  good idea to create temporary workspaces for cases like this?

Comment: I would change layout stuff via TypoScript and Templates and for that you could use an condition. But i guess your "layout" stuff is something different than i think off;)
I think two overlapping workspaces should not harm, if there are not to many people and edits involved.

Comment: I think of something like a different templavoila template for the page.

Comment: well, i guess if you create another workspace, and nobody edits the pages in the first workspace, it should be no problem.